# Listen for variable changes

Tags: android, variables, triggers

Can I somehow create a listener (that is not a button) that listens for a variable change (in the application scope), and when the change occur, execute some code?

If that is possible, can someone give me an example of how this is done the best way?

If you need more context to answer the question (code etc..) I can provide it. But right now I just want to get a general understanding of this.

Comment: What changes this variable? It might be better to use that code/callback/... instead of monitoring the variable itself

Comment: for example if im listening for GPS coordinates. I know one can trigger code through the location listener object, but i feel more comfortable if i could create my own methods to monitor the variable.

Comment: @metalurgus suggestion should work for you. Instead of setting YourClass.position  = new_gps_position you would do YourClass.setNewPosition(position) where you could run/schedule further actions

Comment: I'll tro to experiment some with this later today. I'll be back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quite awesome [example](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2011/11/android-architecture-part-1-intro/)

```
public class InformationVo extends SimpleObservable<InformationVo> {

    private String name;
    private String urls;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setUrls(String urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
        notifyObservers(this);
    }

    public int getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyObservers(this);
    }
}
```

*Here is the observer class that you want*

```
public class SimpleObservable<T> implements EasyObservable<T> {

    private final ArrayList<OnChangeListener<T>> listeners = new ArrayList<OnChangeListener<T>>();


    public void addListener(OnChangeListener<T> listener) {
        synchronized (listeners) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeListener(OnChangeListener<T> listener) {
        synchronized (listeners) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    protected void notifyObservers(final T model) {
        synchronized (listeners) {
            for (OnChangeListener<T> listener : listeners) {
                listener.onChange(model);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you a lot Soham! I belive this is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable private, and create a setter for it. And call your listener method inside the setter after changing variable

Comment: I am not sure if this is what im after, could you provide an example? forgive my ignorance.